# java method to log the row, column location

Tags: java, arrays, logging, random, methods

I am working on an assignment for an online JAVA class, and I have become stuck on a part of a problem. I am admittedly a complete newbie when it comes to JAVA, though I did well with BASIC I just can't wrap my head around some of this stuff. Here is what I need to do:

> Write a method called createCoords that will search the 2D array looking for any value that is evenly divisible by 3.  Once you have found a number you should log the row, column location. This means when your method finishes it should produce a list of coordinates that I can use to plot my graph.  This method must also return the number of coordinates that are divisible by 3 so that I know how many points there are to plot.
>
> I am not particular as to how the coordinates are returned back as long as I get a list of the row, column locations.  So, I will leave it to you to work out a mechanism for returning the values. Some possibilities are:
>
> -String
>
> -Array
>
> -2D Array

I am currently just unsure of what to do. Here is my code so far, where I believe I have createCoord down to where it divides by three and makes a count. What escapes me is the act of logging:

```
package lab14;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lab14 {

public int[][] create2DArray()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int[][] array = new int[10][10];
    for(int row = 1; row <= 10; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 1; col <= 10; col++)
        {
            array[row-1][col-1] = r.nextInt(100);
        }
    }
    return array;
}

public int createCoords(int[] array, int x)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < x;i++)
            {
                if(array[i]% 3 == 0)
                {
                    count ++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }

public void print2DArray(int[][] array)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[row][col] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int ar[][];        
    Lab14 c = new Lab14();
    ar = c.create2DArray();
    c.print2DArray(ar);
}    
}
```

Comment: First of all don't do row = 1 and then row - 1, just start at 0 god damn it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example generates a list of coordinates. I have tried to keep your code (although formatted a bit):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.String;

public class Test {

    public static class Coord {
        public int row;
        public int col;
    }

    public int[][] create2DArray() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int[][] array = new int[10][10];
        for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                array[row][col] = r.nextInt(100);
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    public void print2DArray(int[][] array) {
        for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                System.out.print(array[row][col] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public List<Coord> getResult(int[][] array) {
        List<Coord> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                if (array[row][col] % 3 == 0) {
                    Coord coord = new Coord();
                    coord.row = row;
                    coord.col = col;
                    result.add(coord);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ar[][];        
        Test c = new Test();
        ar = c.create2DArray();
        c.print2DArray(ar);

        List<Coord> coords = c.getResult(ar);
        for (Coord coord: coords) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%d, %d", coord.row, coord.col));
        }
    }
}
```

`getResult` generates the list (array) that your assignment asked for.

Answer (score 0):

use a 2D array to log:

```
int ar[][];
int coordsAr[][] = new int [10][2]; // 2 columns to store the row index and the column index of the element in ar[][]  

public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
   Lab14 c = new Lab14();
   ar = c.create2DArray();
   c.print2DArray(ar);
   int count = c.createCoords(ar);
}

public int createCoords(int[][] array)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
              if(array[i]% 3 == 0)
              {
                  coordsAr[count] = {i,j};
                  count ++;
              }
        }
        return count;
}
```